# Carriage-returns are not applied when running `tail -f` in the background while running `docker exec -it` in the foreground

Tags: macos, docker, tail, tty

When I run `tail -f` in the background and `docker exec -it` in the foreground, the outputs of tail-command are corrupted.

For example, when I run the following commands:

```
$ tail -f log.txt &
$ docker exec -it my-container /bin/bash
```

and I append the following 3 lines to log.txt:

```
cat
dog
bird
```

then I get the following strange outputs:

```
root@4083b121d1793:~# cat
                         dog
                            bird
```

Notice the line breaks.
I'm guessing carriage returns are not applied.

Why does this strange behavior occur?
Is there any solution?

---

**Update**

Versoins:

- Docker Desktop for Mac 3.2.1
- Docker Engine 20.10.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to happen because of the call to [MakeRaw()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/moby/term@v0.0.0-20201110203204-bea5bbe245bf#MakeRaw) in the docker CLI. The docs explain that the function turns the file descriptor (stdin) into "raw mode" so it can be restored to its original state once the terminal session ends. These function calls all happen when setting up the interactive exec session in the CLI in [hijack.go](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/d3c36a2a738ae14c8edc2af12b45917e206b58e7/cli/command/container/hijack.go#L74) in the docker/cli source code.

[This](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/d3c36a2a738ae14c8edc2af12b45917e206b58e7/cli/streams/in.go#L28-L34) is where that happens in the source code. You can see from this that if you set the `NORAW` environment variable, you get the normal output:

```golang
// SetRawTerminal sets raw mode on the input terminal
func (i *In) SetRawTerminal() (err error) {
    if os.Getenv("NORAW") != "" || !i.commonStream.isTerminal {
        return nil
    }
    i.commonStream.state, err = term.SetRawTerminal(i.commonStream.fd)
```

Here is how I tested this, setting the variable `NORAW` when running the exec command:

Terminal 1:

```sh
$ tail -f log.txt
$ NORAW=1 docker exec -it containername /bin/bash
root@docker:/work$
```

Terminal 2:

```sh
$ echo -e "something\nto\ntest" >> log.txt
```

Back in Terminal 1:

```sh
root@docker:/work$ something
to
test
```

I had reproduced exactly what you had before but I happened to be testing on Windows and in WSL2.

However, when `NORAW` is set, you will not be restored as usual to your original terminal session. After `^D` or `exit`, you will the last terminal prompt will immediately be pasted where your cursor is:

```
root@docker:/work$   $
^ docker prompt      ^ original terminal prompt session
```

Comment: does line editing still work correctly in bash?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Do you mean I can use backspace and bash readline `^A`, `^W`, etc? If so, then yes, I can backspace and edit the lines as usual when using `NORAW=1`. What the `MakeRaw()` does I believe is only to restore the terminal to its original state before you called `docker exec`